# Command works manually in bash but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, powershell

We are using Powershell version 5.1.18362.1171 on Windows 10.

If we run the following command:

```
ssh -i id_rsa user@192.168.1.1 'exec bash -l';
```

And then manually run this command in the opened bash console:

```
/usr/bin/o3d3xx-reboot
```

The script works correctly without errors and in the end reboots.
However, if we try to run this code automatically with the code below,
it will always fail in some error inside the reboot script:

```
ssh -i id_rsa user@192.168.1.1 '/usr/bin/o3d3xx-reboot';
```

Is there any way to run this script/binary without manual input, the same way it works in the first version?

Comment: Have you tried the ssh '-t' option to force a terminal allocation? If o3d3xx-reboot needs a pty for some reason, this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh -i id_rsa myuser@myip "bash --login -c 'cd /usr/bin/ && o3d3xx-reboot && exit'";
```

Seems that there were missing environment variables, so the script didn't work. I used the script above which loads the environment the same way as if I was logged in and typed the commands manually.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you give us the logfile describing why the reboot didn't happen it is difficult to guess what the issue is.

You can probably workaround the issue by invoking bash in your ssh, executing the command, and terminating the ssh connection immediately, like this:

```bsh
ssh you@yourserver "bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; /usr/bin/o3d3xx-reboot; exit') -l"
```

The fact that you invoke `bash` with `-l` seems to indicate that your `o3d3xx-reboot` executable needs something from `/etc/profile`. You might want to look there to make a less hacky solution.